# Do you know how to implement transactions in Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, castle

I decided to make a system for a client using [Castle ActiveRecord](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517021542/http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html), everything went well until I found that the transactions do not work, for instance;

```
               TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope();

               try
               {
                   member.Save();

                   //This is just to see transaction working
                   throw new Exception("Exception");  

                   foreach (qfh.Beneficiary b1 in l)
                   {
                       b1.Create();
                   }


               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {

                   t.VoteRollBack();
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }
               finally
               {
                   t.Dispose();
               }
```

But it doesn't work, I throw an Exception just to try the transaction rolls back, but for my surprise I see that the first [Save] records into the database. What is happening?

I'm new on Castle and NHibernate, firstly I saw it very attractive and I decided to go on with it and MySQL (I've never worked with this DB), I tried ActiveWriter and it seemed very promising but after a long and effortly week I see this issue and now I feel like I'm stuck and like I've wasted my time. It is supposed to be easy but right now I'm feeling a frustated cause I cannot find enough information to make this workout, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben's got it. That doc is a little confusing. Refer to the last block [on the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20080417014143/http://www.castleproject.org/ActiveRecord/documentation/v1rc1/usersguide/scopes.html), "Nested transactions".

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap the code in a session scope, like this:

```
using(new SessionScope())
{
   a.Save();
   b.Save();
   c.Save();
}
```

Read more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080417014143/http://www.castleproject.org:80/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/usersguide/scopes.html).

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed, it happened that I was doing wrong, I overrode the Save method of the Member class and made sessionScope inside and inside of it a transaction scope, so when a involved all of that in a transaction scope it saved in the database, so when I threw the exception everything was already saved, I think that's it.

All in all, thanks for the help.